# Error in Xilinx for case statement (case-when)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity sammy_2018314405 is
    Port ( codeword : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
           syndrome : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           dataword : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end sammy_2018314405;

architecture Behavioral of sammy_2018314405 is

signal s : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal b3, b2, b1, b0, q2, q1, q0 : std_logic;
signal temp : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

begin

b3 <= codeword(6);
b2 <= codeword(5);
b1 <= codeword(4);
b0 <= codeword(3);
q2 <= codeword(2);
q1 <= codeword(1);
q0 <= codeword(0);

s(0) <= b0 xor b1 xor b2 xor q0;
s(1) <= b1 xor b2 xor b3 xor q1;
s(2) <= b0 xor b1 xor b3 xor q2;

temp <= (b3,b2,b1,b0,q2,q1,q0);
```

--this part show error, can I put case in the middle of the code?

```
process(s)
    begin
        case s is
            when "001" => temp(0) <= not temp(0);
            when "010" => temp(1) <= not temp(1);
            when "011" => temp(5) <= not temp(5);
            when "100" => temp(2) <= not temp(2);
            when "101" => temp(3) <= not temp(3);
            when "110" => temp(6) <= not temp(6);
            when "111" => temp(4) <= not temp(4);
           when others => null;
        end case;
    end process;

syndrome(2 downto 0) <= s(2 downto 0);
dataword(3 downto 0) <= temp(6 downto 3);


end Behavioral;
```

Line 51: Net <temp[6]> is already driven by input port <codeword[6]>.
Net <temp[5]> is already driven by input port <codeword[5]>.
(This is code for 7 4 Hamming decoder.)
What should I do?

Comment: You have two processes driving the elements of temp. The unlabeled process statement  and the unlabeled concurrent assignment statement that is elaborated into a process statement. Provide a [mcve], there are other errors.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to Xilinx. I am not sure which part of the code is having error so I include the whole code. I am trying to implement a 7 4 hamming decoder.

Comment: What should you do? Redesign so that signal temp doesn't have multiple drivers.